# ASP.NET Form Validation Doesn't work first time

Tags: asp.net, html, validation, forms, menu

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="LoginPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="login">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" Text="<%$ Resources:Login, UserNameField %>" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" MaxLength="12" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUsername" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" ValidationGroup="vgLogin" SetFocusOnError="true"
                        ErrorMessage="*" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:Login, UserNameRequired %>" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" Text="<%$ Resources:Login, PasswordField %>" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" MaxLength="12" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPassword" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" ValidationGroup="vgLogin" SetFocusOnError="true"
                        ErrorMessage="*" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:Login, PasswordRequired %>"  runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="label">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRemember" Text="<%$ Resources:Login, RememberField %>" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemember" Checked="true" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:Login, RememberToolTip %>" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="buttons">
                <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Text="<%$ Resources:Login, Command %>" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="vgLogin" CausesValidation="true" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The first time around, validators won't check whether the fields are completed or not, the form just gets submitted no matter what, after that initial hiccup, the form validates correctly each time.

I know I can just ask (and should, regardless) if `Page.IsValid` at server-side, but I still would like the validation to correctly alert the user input mistake the first time around instead of waiting for the server response first.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of asp.net are you using? The asp.net in validators in v2.0 don't work with updatepanels (because updatepanels didn't exists when v2.0 was released) but they do with v3.5. Also an example with text instead of the Resources:Login options would be preferred as it makes setting up a test case faster

Comment: I tried the provided code sample, and couldn't simulate your case. I do recommend that you debug validation js using either I.E developer tools or firebug (start with `ValidatorOnLoad` and `ValidatorCommonOnSubmit` functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load order of the JS files may be causing problems here, if there are dependencies between them. Because of random latency some dependencies might not have been satisfied yet, causing functionality to break. Your console might give hints if this is the case. On subsequent page loads everything appears to be fine, because the JS files were cached and are now loaded without latency in their proper order.

Things to try:

- Play around with JS inclusion order
- Try to postpone the use of
  dependencies until after body.onload
  fired.
- You may also want to try out
  [the rather involved solution
  offered on aspdotnetfaq](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-control-ASP-NET-Validator-Controls-Client-Side-validation-from-JavaScript.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar happen when there was a large amount of javascript being loaded, or when there is an unrelated javascript error (usually but not always related to the large amount of javascript.

Comment: my javascript is kept to a minimum, in fact I thought it had something to do with me having a onclientclick event but I removed that and it still doesn't validate the first time around..

Answer (score 0):

This may not be much of an answer, but Ive run into similar issues in the past.  ASP Validation Controls dont really seem to "play nice" inside of UpdatePanels.   *I think* the reason is that when they attempt to perform any type of validation, they also attempt to write to the pages viewstate.  The viewstate however is outside of the Update Panel's area, meaning that you are update the "middle" of the page, without the entire page's state getting updated, making the status of your controls out of sync.

In any case, to prove this, remove the update panel from around your controls, submit your form, and check if your validation controls work.

Unfortunately, for a workaround, Ive created custom javascript functions to perform client side validation, and then also perform server side validation and display any errors.  In these scenario's, Ive avoided using ASP .NET Validation controls.

Good luck =\